# How can we validate many text fields at once in a sign up form in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I am making a signup form in flutter and I have validate various fields such as first-name, last-name, mobile number, email id, pin-code, state, district.

How do I validate this many text fields together?

Comment: You mean only after a click of a button or after the user has completed inputing all fieelds?

Comment: I mean after the user has completed inputting all fields

Answer (score 0):

provide a key inside State

final _formKey = GlobalKey();

wrap all your textformfield/textfield with Form widget

inside form widget there is a key property "key: _formKey",

example. of validator inside textform field

```
  validator: (value) {
                          if (value.length < 10) {
                            return 'Phone number must be 10 digits';
                          }
                          else{
                           return null;
                          }
                      },
```

finally where ever is you submit button use it as example given below

```
 onPressed: () {
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            postEnquiries(
                              context,
                              nameController.text,
                              emailController.text,
                              phoneController.text,
                            );
                          }
                        },
```

here is a bit old code that i had used for validate form

```
      final TextEditingController name;
  final TextEditingController emailID;
  final TextEditingController countryCode;
  final TextEditingController phoneNumber;
  final ConsultationFormPage widget;

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 50),
          Text('Consultation', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24)),
          Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.19),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: name,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter a valid Name';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Name'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: emailID,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email ID'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter a valid email address';
                        }
                        if (!value.contains('@')) {
                          return 'Email is invalid, must contain @';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: countryCode,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: '+91'),
                              enabled: false,
                            ),
                            width: 70),
                        SizedBox(width: 15),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: phoneNumber,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Phone Number'),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value.length < 10) {
                                return 'Phone number must be 10 digits';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 50),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: double.maxFinite,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            postEnquiries(
                              context,
                              name.text,
                              emailID.text,
                              phoneNumber.text,
                              widget.data.packageName,
                              widget.data.propertyName,
                              widget.data.signUp,
                            );
                          }
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18),
                          child: Text("Book Design Consultation", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a local variable of Global Key

**final _formKey = GlobalKey();**

Add Widget **Form** and assign its property **key = _formKey**

Wrap all FormTextField inside widget **Form**

Use **validate** property of FormTextField to validate inputs.

Now, we can validate the all textformfields with raisedbutton.

```
RaisedButton(
 color: Colors.blue,
 child: Text('Save'),
 onPressed: () {
     if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
      showDialog(
      context: context,
      child: AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Validated'),
      )
    );
  }
},
),
```

Full code to validate **textField1** and **textField2** on click of **Save** button.

```
class EventAddPage extends StatelessWidget {
EventAddPage({super.key});

final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    textFieldBox1(),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    textFieldBox2(),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    submitButton(),
                  ],
                ),
              ))
         ],
       ),
   ),
  );
 }

TextFormField textFieldBox1() {
  return TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: 'Title in Arabic',
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    ),
    validator: (value) => _validateField(value),
  );
}

TextFormField textFieldBox2() {
  return TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: 'Title in English',
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    ),
    validator: (value) => _validateField(value),
  );
}

Row submitButton() {
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Save', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0)),
        onPressed: () {
          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {}
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
 }

  String? _validateField(String? value) {
    return value!.isEmpty ? '*Required Field' : null;
  }
}
```